# On my Sign In page for my website the box i have it in is intentionally blurry but when i go onto my phone its clear

Tags: mobile-website

On my website I have a blurred box that has my Sign In function in and it works perfect on desktop but once I use my website on my phone it doesn't show the blur and makes the box clear, I have been trying to fix this issue for some time now, any help is much appreciated.

I tried implementing some code someone on here told me to use but that still didn't fix it.